# Interaction plot for lme4 in r

Tags: r, lme4, interaction

I would like to plot an interaction effect for two continuous variables in a multilevel model. The model is the following:

```
lme4::glmer(final$trust ~ final$educ.c + 
final$age.c + 
final$gender + 
final$C14 RESPONDENT_OCCUPATION_SCALE + 
final$tot_country.c + 
final$int_use.c + 
final$educ.c*final$acc.c + 
(final$educ.c | final$Country), 
data = final, 
family = binomial, 
weights = final$W85_WEIGHT_EU27_+_TR_+_HR_+_NO_+_CH_+_IS, nAGQ=0, 
control = glmerControl(optimizer = "optimx", calc.derivs = FALSE, optCtrl = list(method = "nlminb", starttests = FALSE, kkt = FALSE)))
```

The interaction I am interested in is `final$educ.c*final$acc.c`, the dependent variable is dichotomous and after have consulted various websites and similar issues, I am still struggling with it. Does anyone have a suggestion about how to do it?

Comment: First things first: Remove `final$` from the formula. You specify the data.frame as `data` and there can be unexpected consequences if you include it in the formula.

Comment: You are right @Roland, thank you!

Comment: Take a look at Thomas Leeper's `margins` package, or the `effects` package which is older but quite solid.

Comment: Thank you @dash2, it worked with `effects`!